# .bs files are generated while running a test in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm facing a strange issue while using Eclipse-Indigo (32 bit).
I'm running my code on my machine and code is not getting executed correctly, there is no exception/error shown but files with extenion ".bs" are getting generated.

The same code is executed correctly on a different machine. Can anyone suggest what might be the issue here?

Can anyone please atelast answer what does ".bs" files stand for? Is it bitstream?

Comment: What's the difference between these machines?

Comment: only processor; even the RAM and Java versions are same.

Comment: Same Eclipse with same plugins and same OS, etc?

Comment: Eclipse versions are different. One has Helios while other has Indigo. The one with Indigo is having this problem.

Comment: I'm sure different eclipse versions has nothing to do with it. And this might be because of either differences in the jar versions used at client and server sides OR because of different JDK versions at client and server sides OR may be because I'm using a jar compiled in JDK x on system having JDK y...Not sure, still struggling with this, will post the answer if I could find anything concrete.

Comment: pls show us the content of *.bs file

Comment: the contents of ".bs" are not readable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, so finally after lots of debugging, I was able to find solution to this.

Before I talk about solution, first thing, this has nothing to do with different eclipse versions or different java versions.

So, the .bs files were generated because the client and server had different versions of project jars (not the third party jars).
My client project in Eclipse was referring to older jars while the server had latest jars.

I think this problem will only occur if you have multiple dependent projects or project jars.